# Install pear on MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl

I try to install pear:

`curl -O  https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`

`php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar`

And I get warning:

> PHP Warning:  require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/PEAR/REST/13.php):
>   failed to open stream: phar error: "PEAR/REST/13.php" is not a file in
>   phar "go-pear.phar" in
>   phar:///Users/maksat/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Config.php on line 2067

Directory `/Users/maksat/pear/bin` is empty

How can I resolve this problem?

My OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: I solved this problem with ```curl -s -O http://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar```. Link: https://tobschall.de/2018/08/07/pear-on-mojave/

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 1809 using PHP 7.3.3 and using `install-pear-nozlib.phar` didn't work, instead it seems to be a very outdated version of the installation script not properly distinguishing system wide vs. local installation at least on Windows and such. `[PEAR] Archive_Tar: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\Archive`

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems as well, this worked for me:

`curl -0 https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io/kbfiles/pear/go-pear.phar`

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 10 1809 using PHP 7.3.3 and the linked file resolved the issue for me as well. It seems to be a slightly older version of the installation script, 1.10.7 vs. 1.10.8.

Comment: While installation seems to work and the first questions regarding paths looked the same between the linked and the official version of the script, I'm running in multiple `ACCESS DENIED`-errors on Windows because `pear` wants to write to `C:\Windows\pear.ini` during operations like `pear channel-update pear.php.net`. Installing docs for packages fails as well: `ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\Text_Diff\docs\examples` Not sure if this has to with the older installation script or `pear` simply still is broken regarding different users.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10887729/9430588) correctly suggests you may use [this tool](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) from Xdebug & check for recommendations for your particular case.